# Resources to practice for Life in the UK test?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizenship

Are there any resources where I can practice for the [Life in the UK test](https://www.gov.uk/life-in-the-uk-test)?

After reading the **official** [**book**](https://www.tsoshop.co.uk/Life-in-the-UK/Life-in-the-United-Kingdom-A-Guide-for-New-Residents/?TrackID=002353) it just seems a lot to memorize, and I'm looking for an interactive way to help remember the more important elements.

Comment: Hey, have you tried out the sample tests available online (whether it be official or unofficial), and do you find them help?

Comment: @B.Liu That is exactly what I'm looking for, sample tests online, the ones that others have used and can say that it helped them

Answer (score 2):

When my wife was practicing for her Life in the UK test a few years ago she found [TheUKTest](https://www.theuktest.com) website useful in addition to the official book referenced in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have studied and passed my Life in the UK test in December 2018.

I bought the official book, read it, enjoyed it a lot actually! And then did the online [unofficial mockup tests from Life in the UK Test Web](https://lifeintheuktestweb.co.uk/exams) and.. failed them miserably.

Wasn't motivated to re-read the book, so gave up for a few months, until I decided to just do and do the unofficial mockup tests over and over again - specifically [the 1-15 exams (mockup tests)](https://lifeintheuktestweb.co.uk/exams), I did that for about a week until I always answered all the questions 100% correctly every time.

That gave me confidence it might be time to spend £50 on the official test, I booked it and when it came to it I passed it in about 6 minutes.